# Помогите с заданием

Tags: python, if

Даны три целых числа. Найдите наибольшее из них (программа должна вывести ровно одно целое число).

Используйте ровно два оператора сравнения (>, <, >=, <=) для решения этой задачи. Использовать функции `max` и `min`, а также логические операции `and` нельзя.

*Входные данные:* Вводится три целых числа, не превосходящие 100 по абсолютному значению.
*Выходные данные:* Выведите ответ на задачу.

Можно использовать только 2 оператора сравнения.

Comment: `if a > b && a > c print a` и по аналогии.

Comment: Что мешает тебе решить эту задачу самостоятельно?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 3
b = 0
c = 5

max_num = a
if b > max_num:
    max_num = b
if c > max_num:
    max_num = c

print(max_num)
```

Comment: Можно использовать только 2 оператора сравнения, поэтому по аналогии не получится

Comment: Я уже решил, спасибо

Comment: @Никита так поделитесь решением)